# $scope data is not updating in view for the first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

controller.js

```
$scope.getElectInfo=function(){
        var selectedVal = $("#countriesList option:selected").val();
        if (selectedVal != 0) {
        $.get(APP_URL+ "/political/ElectionType/GetElectionTypesByCountry?countryId="
                                + selectedVal,
                        function(data, status) {
                        $scope.data1=data;
                        console.log($scope.data1);
                        });
                    $scope.Structure = true;    
    }else
    {
    $scope.Structure = false;
    }
        }
```

html

```
 <select id="countriesList" ng-change="getElectInfo()" ng-model="getElectionInfo">
       </select>
       <div ng-show="Structure" class="content">

 <figure class="org-chart cf">
<ul class="administration">
  <li>                  
    <ul class="director">
      <li>
        <ul class="subdirector">
        </ul>
        <ul class="departments cf">                             
          <li><a ><span ng-repeat="cname in country">{{cname.countryName}}</span></a></li>

          <li class="department dep-b" ng-repeat="types in data1">
            <a ><span>{{types.name}}</span></a>
          </li>
```

In the above controller.js i am getting the country wise election types data,in the html page when i select the country for the first time $scope.data1 is not updating in view,select second time its updating can any one help me what is the problem!

Comment: Remove the line to get selected value and replace it by your variable getElectionInfo.
Ensure your condition "!= 0" is true and check the value of getElectionInfo

Comment: no luck,same problem

Comment: Did you check value of getElectionInfo ? Are you sure that the request is doing and return an array? Can you provide request result for the first time ?

Comment: yes i am getting the getElectionInfo value is 1, if not selecting the country from select box getting getElectionInfo  to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

finally i got it,

need to place $scope.$apply(); in function(data, status) { }

Comment: hum... i see. Can i recommend to you a little update to avoid to call $scope.$apply() ?
You must call it because you use jquery http query and you are not in angular digest cycle. Inject $http angular service to do your http request. Angular will automatically call his digest phase to update the view.

Comment: how can i achieve this please help me!

Comment: In your controller inject $http like this :
app.controller('controllerName', ['$http', function($http) { ... } ])

and use this to did your request : 
$http.get(APP_URL+ "/political/ElectionType/GetElectionTypesByCountry?countryId="+ selectedVal).then(function sucess(response) { $scope.data1= response.data;  }, function error(error) { /* handle error */} )